# Conditions for zipped lists in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, zip

I have prepared an example for my problem. (Btw. number of digits is equal in both lists).

```
lst = [10,20,30,40,30,20,70,10,20,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,60]
lst2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

sup = zip(lst,lst2)
res = [j for i, j, k in zip(sup, sup[1:], sup[2:]) if i < j and j > k and j >= 60.0]

print res
```

It suppose to find those values, but it doesn't. Any ideas?

```
[(70, 7) (80, 17)]
```

Comment: For starters, you're comparing two-tuples to scalars, which I doubt is intentional.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I hope you understand that `sup` is a tuple and not element in `zip(sup, sup[1:], sup[2:])`

Comment: Well as a newbie in Python, all I can say I made this example of my more complex problem. I have a data which is plotted, and I use this procedure when I want to find certain digits with that procedure, like here it suppose to find numbers above 60, and it works. When I use zip function because I have plots so to yaxis I need data from xaxis, everything crack and I stuck at this point. Still not sure if you can understand me correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear for me what you want to get with this.

you can use:

```
sup = list(zip(lst,lst2))
```

It will return a list of tuples.

After that you can compare using your list comprehension.

I believe what you want is

```
res = [j for i, j, k in zip(sup, sup[1:], sup[2:]) if i < j and j > k and j[0] >= 60.0]
```

This returned [(70,7), (80,17)].

Note that i, j and k are tuples! That's why I selected j[0] to check if it is >= 60

Comment: Ah... Great you have perfectly answered my question. The problem was I didn't know that this `j[0]` was crucial. Thanks a lot :)